# How do I remove the whitespace from the first iteration of my for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, whitespace

Code:

```
triangle_char = input('Enter a character:\n')
triangle_height = int(input('Enter triangle height:\n'))
print('')

for i in range(triangle_height):
    updatedChar = ' '.join([triangle_char]*i) 
    print(triangle_char + ' ' + updatedChar + ' ')
    i += 1
```

The output is correct but I can't seem to get rid of the extra " " whitespace at the end of the first iteration.

```
Example Output:

% # How to remove this whitespace but keep the others
% %
% % %
```

Comment: Can you explain what does your expected output look like

Comment: side note: `i +=1` seems smelly to me, you are already looping with a `for` loop, `i` will be updated automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple `updatedChar` by `i + 1` and print it without appending the sign again. You can also remove the `i += 1`, it has no effect

```
for i in range(triangle_height):
    updated_char = ' '.join(triangle_char * (i + 1))
    print(updated_char)
```

Output

```
%
% %
% % %
```

Comment: now that's just totally skipping over the first iteration, which I want to still print the first character in the triangle.

Comment: @svnrod It does print it, did you try?

Comment: thats my fault, I didn't update something but now it's totally fixed. I see where I went wrong now, appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

strip() should do what you want

```
triangle_char = input('Enter a character:\n')
triangle_height = int(input('Enter triangle height:\n'))
print('')
for i in range(triangle_height+1):
    updatedChar = ' '.join([triangle_char]*i)
    print((triangle_char + ' ' + updatedChar + ' ').strip())
    i += 1
```